# Need help with solving this puzzle about geometric probability

Tags: probability

"If 75% of all women are tall, 75% of all women are brunette, and 75% of all women are pretty, what is the
minimum percentage who are tall, brunette, pretty women?"

The solution claims to be 25%, and it is solved by geometric probability. My question though is how exactly is it calculated?

Answer (score 3):

The percent of  women who are not pretty is 25%.  The percentage of  women who are not tall is 25%.  The percentage of women who are not brunette are 25%.  If these are completely disjoint the remaining 25% of the women must be all three.

Answer (score 2):

There might be other geometric probability ways, I'll solve it using only lines.

Let there be 3 rows of 100 cells, with tall, brunette and pretty women in rows 1,2,3.
Let tall women occupy 1 - 75
To minimize overlap, start from the other end for brunettes who occupy 26 - 100
Common part is only the "middle" which extends from 26-75
Put 25 pretty women at both ends, 1-25 and 76-100 and 25 somewhere in the "middle":

The "middle" is common to all, so the *minimum* % that is tall, brunette and pretty is 25%
[The maximum % is obviously 75% ]

Answer (score 1):

Think of a house with four rooms and the volunteer women all outside.  To find the lowest possible amount of tall, brunette & pretty women, you want to disqualify as many as you can.  Start by putting all the non-tall women in the first disqualifying room.  That’s 25% of the volunteer women because 75% are tall.  From the volunteer women remaining outside, put all the non-brunette women in the second disqualifying room.  That’s 25% of the volunteer women at most — less if some of the non-brunettes already ended up in the first disqualifying room.  Finally, from the volunteer women remaining outside, put all the non-pretty women in the third disqualifying room. That’s 25%, or less if some of the non-pretty women already ended up in the first or second disqualifying rooms.  The disqualified number is the HIGHEST POSSIBLE number when the second and third rooms have exactly 25% each — that is, when all the non-brunette volunteer women are in the second room and all the non-pretty volunteer women are in the third room; in other words, when the non-tall, non-brunette & non-pretty groups DO NOT OVERLAP.  That situation leaves the LOWEST POSSIBLE number of tall, brunette & pretty volunteer women in the last room (or outside)— 25%.  The house and rooms aren’t needed to solve the problem, but they can help you visualize and keep the groups separated in your head.

The big concepts are that: 1) you want to maximize the size of any group that has a quality opposite to one you want to minimize; and 2) you, thus, would want to eliminate any overlap among such opposite groups (so that one person cannot be in more than one such group — as opposed to one  person in the first group, another in the second group, etc.).   In Ro•man terms, you would want the largest numbered legions and no one serving in more than one of your legions so that the opposite legion(s) would be the smallest.